# Как реализовать градиентный цвет линии графика excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, office, диаграммы

Добрый день. Хочу нарисовать график с градиентным цветом линии используя библиотеку microsoft.office.interop.excel. Не могу найти как это реализовать используя С#. Результат функции представлен на правой части скрина. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать 3 цвета, как в левой части скрина.

Код, строящий график:

```
        private void WriteToXlsx()
    {
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;
        //Книга.
        ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        //Таблица.
        ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];
        //Cтартовая ячейка [i,j]
        int i = 4;
        int j = 9;
        int x;

        //Заполнение ячеек-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        for (x = 0; x <= count_results; x++)
        {

            ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + x, j] = times_of_speed[x].ToString(); ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + x, j + 1] = pig_speed[x].ToString();
        }


        Range chartRange;

        ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)ObjWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        ChartObject myChart = (ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 250);
        Chart xlChart = myChart.Chart;

        Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

        chartRange = ObjWorkSheet.Range[ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i, j], ObjWorkSheet.Cells[i + x - 1, j + 1]];
        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
        chartPage.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLineStacked;

        //Проверка существования директории и ее созлание
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Выгрузки данных по остановам"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Выгрузки данных по остановам");
        }

        //Сохранение файла без запроса на перезапись--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        ObjWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Выгрузки данных по остановам\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + " Выгрузка из ПЛК данных по остановам.xlsx", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        ObjExcel.DisplayAlerts = true;


        ObjExcel.Visible = true;
        ObjExcel.UserControl = true;

    }
```

[image: справа результат программы, слева - цель]